# Is there a way to individualize UI on slideshows/cards generated from firestore? Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I want the user to favorite things and they can but the downside is when I change the icon to show that they've click on the button, all the slides' icons changes as well. How can I individualize each slide so when I do a if/else statement on the UI, it'll only effect that specific slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to help without looking at the actual code but to answer your question, you could try adding a `selected` column with `boolean` value in your firestore table so when a card is clicked, you can update the column value for that item to `true` and refresh the state so that only the card with `true` is changed leaving rest of the cards unchanged with `selected` as `false`.

Example psuedo code:

```
return FutureBuilder(
        future: getDataFromFirestore(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (itemIndex) {
                Macro macro = snapshot.data[itemIndex];
                return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data["title"]),
                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data["subtitle"]),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: snapshot.data["selected"] ? Icons.check : Icons.add //If card is selected, display checked icon else display add icon
                      onPressed: () async {setState(() {}); //Refresh state}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that worked.